# Get all regexp matches in buffer as a list

Tags: elisp, regular-expressions

On the Code Golf Stack Exchange site today, I found [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44298/33016) in Clojure to the question "Get all links on a webpage".

```
(->> (slurp "http://www.stroustrup.com")
     (re-seq #"(?:http://)?www(?:[./#\+-]\w*)+"))
```

Without the fancy macro, it's just this:

```
(re-seq #"(?:http://)?www(?:[./#\+-]\w*)+" (slurp "http://www.stroustrup.com"))
```

This returns the list:

```
("http://www.morganstanley.com/" "http://www.cs.columbia.edu/" "http://www.cse.tamu.edu" ...)
```

Can I do something similar in Emacs Lisp?

Perhaps a function like `(re-seq regexp (buffer-string))` that returns `'(firstmatch secondmatch thirdmatch ...)`?

Comment: This is what `M-x occur` does, but I'd look inside for more low-level functions to do that.

Comment: @wvxvw That's a good point, I didn't even think about `occur`. I'll have to look through its source.

Comment: I looked inside, and oh woe, that code does too much and it's not easy to repurpose it, not at all. My next candidate would be `s.el`, but maybe there's more out there. Here: https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-match-strings-all-regex-string how about this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is how you can do it based on strings, as requested.

```
(defun re-seq (regexp string)
  "Get a list of all regexp matches in a string"
  (save-match-data
    (let ((pos 0)
          matches)
      (while (string-match regexp string pos)
        (push (match-string 0 string) matches)
        (setq pos (match-end 0)))
      matches)))

; Sample URL
(setq urlreg "\\(?:http://\\)?www\\(?:[./#\+-]\\w*\\)+")
; Sample invocation
(re-seq urlreg (buffer-string))
```

Comment: That looks not quite complete, could you expand this to a fully working answer?

Comment: The code was complete, but I also added an example of usage. What else would you like to see?

Comment: This solution is too simple, unfortunately. Try `(re-seq "^.*$" "")`. Valid regexp, valid string, but it never terminates.

Comment: @PhilLord The fix is pretty trivial (just return nil if the string length is 0).

Answer (score 14):

It's probably worth noting that invoking `occur` with the universal argument causes it to populate the `*Occur*` buffer with only matches — no file names, line numbers or header information. When combined with a capture group, this allows one to extract whatever pattern is desired.

For example, `C-u M-x occur` followed by `\"\(.*\)\"` will prompt the user for which capture group to collect (default `\1`), and then place the content of every quoted string into the `*Occur*` buffer.

Comment: This is an excellent tip! You can visit the buffer programatically, like any other, and extract the matches as per. Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I have an emacs lisp answer to that question posted: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44319/18848

Using the same (while (search) (print)) structure you could modify it into a function to push matches in a buffer to a list and return it like this:

```
(defun matches-in-buffer (regexp &optional buffer)
  "return a list of matches of REGEXP in BUFFER or the current buffer if not given."
  (let ((matches))
    (save-match-data
      (save-excursion
        (with-current-buffer (or buffer (current-buffer))
          (save-restriction
            (widen)
            (goto-char 1)
            (while (search-forward-regexp regexp nil t 1)
              (push (match-string 0) matches)))))
      matches)))
```

Comment: Nice answer, note you may want to replace `match-string` with `match-string-no-properties` so the syntax highlight isn't extracted. You may want to pass a `regexp-group-index` to use so you can choose which text is stored.  As well as reversing the order of searching (current list is last-to-first). See this answer which includes a modified version https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38752/2418

Answer (score 4):

Using `s.el` this would've been shorter, but, unfortunately, it gives too many matches:

```
(defun all-urls-in-buffer ()
  (s-match-strings-all
   "\\(?:http://\\)?www\\(?:[./#+-]\\w*\\)+"
   (buffer-string)))
```

If this is ok (the regex for URLs isn't perfect anyway), this just might be shorter, and if not, then I don't think I could make it shorter than Alan Shutko's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let me just mention why I think this is not implemented in the core.
Simply for efficiency reasons: there's no need to copy, create lists,
pass them around and garbage collect them. Instead, store the whole
string as the buffer, and operate with integer match bounds. That's how
`occur` works, for instance: it matches one string at a time and
inserts the match into `*occur*`.  It doesn't match all the strings at
once, make them into the list, loop on the list to insert into
`*occur*` and garbage collect the list and its strings.

Just like you wouldn't write `(do (def x 1) (def x (+ 2 x)))` in
Clojure, you shouldn't by default try to have Elisp behave like a
functional language.  I'd love it if it was, but we have to make due
with what we've got at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If I may be allowed a plug, take a look at my "m-buffer" library.

```
(m-buffer-match buffer "foo")
```

Returns a list of markers to matches to `foo`.