# Simple way to test if string contains positive integer

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to test for whether a string contains a positive integer (1, 2, 3, ...).  By "string contains" I mean the string is only numbers (e.g. "1", "12", "123" but **not** "0", "1.1", "1a", "a1").

My first thought was to test the type and check if it is an integer but first I need to convert to numeric.

```
(typep (string-to-number "23K") 'integer)
;; t
```

This doesn't work because `string-to-number` ignores any trailing characters.

Then I thought I'd use regular expressions to test that every character is in `[0-9]`.

```
(equal (nth 0 (re-seq "[0-9]+" "23K")) "23K")
```

where `re-seq` is taken from [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7148/get-all-regexp-matches-in-buffer-as-a-list) and searches for every occurrence of the regular expression (first arg) in the second arg.

Combining that with a test for the number being greater than 0 I end up with this:

```
(and (equal (nth 0 (re-seq "[0-9]+" "23K")) "23K") 
     (> (string-to-number "23K") 0) )
```

I'm pretty new to lisp programming so I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to recognize positive integers written in decimal expansion: they are the strings that consist only of decimal digits, where at least one of the digits is nonzero.

```
(string-match "\\`[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*\\'" my-string)
```

This allows leading zeros (e.g. `"0123"`); if you don't want that, insist that a nonzero digit comes first.

```
(string-match "\\`[1-9][0-9]*\\'" my-string)
```

If you use regular expressions for other things in the same piece of code, [save the match data](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Saving-Match-Data.html#Saving-Match-Data) around your test.

```
(save-match-data
  (string-match "\\`[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*\\'" my-string))
```

Note that if you try to convert the string to an integer with `string-to-int`, Emacs may make a floating point approximation if the integer is too large. With `parse-integer`, you'll get an integer but with wraparound at 2<sup>*N*</sup> where *N* is the number of bits in an integer in your version of Emacs.

Comment: Nice points on the leading zeroes and the floating point approximations

Comment: You can use `string-match-p` instead of wrapping with `save-match-data`

Answer (score 8):

In `cl` package there's `cl-parse-integer`:

```
(cl-parse-integer "23K") ; errors
(cl-parse-integer "23K" :junk-allowed t)
23
```

Comment: This allows nonpositive integers.

Comment: It also allows you to check for them with normal numeric comparison. `(< (cl-parse-integer "23K" :junk-allowed t) 0)`

Comment: @Gilles yes, but I assumed it to be trivial to write. I doubt there's a specialized function for positive integers only (and probably if there was one, zero would be still treated as positive).