# How to temporarily switch to another major mode in elisp (with-current-mode ?)

Tags: major-mode

*Is there reliable way to temporarily switch the current buffer to another major mode, perform some function, then switch back to the original mode?*

Basically, I was looking for something similar to [with-current-buffer](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-20-2.5/html_node/elisp_400.html) below, but instead of temporarily switching to a different buffer, switch to a different major mode during an action.

> Macro: with-current-buffer buffer body...
>
> The with-current-buffer macro saves the identity of the current
> buffer, makes buffer current, evaluates the body forms, and finally
> restores the buffer. The return value is the value of the last form in
> body. The current buffer is restored even in case of an abnormal exit
> via throw or error

I tried something [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59220/17852) (for reasons also explained there) along the lines of:

```
  (let ((current-mode major-mode))
    (text-mode)
    ;(...)
    (funcall current-mode)
  )
```

to switch to the `text-mode` first, perform the action, and then switch back. This works as expected
only if the action is completed. However, if the action in the middle is canceled or there is an error,
the last step for restoring mode is skipped and the current buffer is stuck in the `text-mode`.

Is there a safe way to do, e.g.  `(with-current-mode "text-mode" (...))`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info. Please don't use tag `elisp` for "How to do...usingElisp?" questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Cleanups` for how to use `unwind-protect`

> The ‘unwind-protect’ construct is essential whenever you temporarily put
> a data structure in an inconsistent state; it permits you to make the
> data consistent again in the event of an error or throw.